# CSR for route on podspace.io

Tags: ssl, openshift, csr, podspace

I want to secure a route on a sub-domain on podspace.io (which is OpenShift/Kubernetes -aaS).  I have purchased a wildcard cert but have yet to activate it.  I'm unsure how to activate it correctly?

Can I generate the CSR using OpenSSL on my workstation, then store the signed files securely and provide them to podspace.io to secure my route?  Assuming this is true, I believe I'll need to generate a request compatible with the OpenShift edge termination, which I believe is HAProxy based?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any PEM formatted certificate to create secure routes on [podspace.io](https://podspace.io). You have the option to upload the PEM files when creating the route. Other than being in PEM format, there aren't any special requirements for SSL certificates.